# This is my Grandfather's patent

Tags: filing

Bruce Percival Warburton is my Grandfather. My Grandmother knew of his invented drill bit but she did not know it was patented. How, out of interest, are these patents located - and now about 50 years later who has the rights to this patent? Bruce is dead, by the way.

Comment: If I helped answer your question, I'd appreciate it if you marked it as answered--it also helps future searchers identify good answers.  Cheers!

Comment: So sorry I completely forgot I posted this question you’re a total star mate  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the patent:  https://www.google.com/patents/US3186501

It looks like it was filed in the US and Germany, and assigned to P & V Mining & Engineering Ltd.

As EntropyWins said, the patent issued in 1965, and thus is long expired, so no one now "owns it" in a meaningful sense.

Comment: The patents were filed by Bruce in London (we are English) but Padley & Venables took out U.S.A. and other patents when the patents were assignewd to Padley &Venabgles.

Answer (score 2):

For the purpose of this answer, I'm assuming you are in the United States.  Patent law varies country to country so this is important, if you aren't in the US, please edit your question.

**Locating a Patent by Inventor Name**

To locate your grandfather's patent, you can just use Google!

- http://www.google.com/advanced_patent_search

  - Enter your Grandfather's name as "Inventor"
- [Here's a patent!](https://www.google.com/patents/US3186501?dq=ininventor:Bruce%20ininventor:Warburton&hl=en&sa=X&ei=irqqVMGQGc-vyATwsYCoAw&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBA)

**Who owns the right to the patent?**

Almost certainly nobody.  Patent rights, from patents filed earlier than 1996 (this is complicated, I'm ignoring for these purposes), expire 17 years from the date the patent was issued.  Using the linked patent above, which issued in 1965, all of the rights expired in the early 1980s.  Still cool though!